# Get count of no of times a sequence appears in a table using sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to get the no of IDs for which the following sequence appears in the table:

```
x    r1   
x    r2
x    r1
y    r2
z    r1
z    r2
```

the table has the following information

```
ID     S1      S2
1      x       r1
1      x       r2
1      x       r1
1      y       r2
1      z       r1
1      z       r2
2      x       r1
2      x       r2
3      x       r1
3      x       r2
3      x       r1
3      y       r2
4      x       r1
4      z       r2
4      x       r1
4      x       r2
4      x       r1
4      y       r2
4      z       r1
4      z       r2
```

I want the result to return a count of 2 as the above mentioned sequence appears for two different IDs.

I hav tried the following code:

```
with c as 
(
select id, count (id) as id_cnt
from table1
group by id
)

select t.id, t.s2, t.s1
from table1 t
join c
on t.id = c.id
and c.id_cnt >= 6
where t.s1 in( 'x', 'y', 'z')
group by t.id, t.s2, t.s1
order by t.id
```

Comment: is there some key (natural or otherwise) to determine sequence?  Or is arbitrarily specified?

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use This Query :

```
 select ID , COUNT(id) AS idCount ,s1,s2 from table1 
 group by ID,s1,s2
```